# Postgresql (pgsql) client expecting sockets in different location from postgrsql-server

Tags: postgresql

While trying to connect to postgres running locally on my workstation, I get:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql -c "create role ..."
could not change directory to "/home/esauer/workspace/cfme"
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

My postgres-server install creates sockets in `/var/run/postgresql`.

How do I get the client to look in the proper location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the `--host` option with `psql --help`.

Then you can make it permanent by setting it in your `.psqlrc` user file.

In your case try:

`psql -h /var/run/postgresql -d your_database`

Comment: So, the default "host" value is "local socket", but that doesn't tell me why it's looking in /tmp/ instead of /var/run for that socket

Comment: OH, got it... 'psql -h /var/run/postgres' points psql to the proper directory for local sockets. Thanks/

Comment: What is the syntax for defining the host in `.psqlrc`? (`\set HOST /var/run/postgresql` did not work.)