# psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, macos

Not really sure what caused this but most likely exiting the terminal while my rails server which was connected to PostgreSQL database was closed (not a good practice I know but lesson learned!)

I've already tried the following:

1. Rebooting my machine (using MBA M1 2020)
2. Restarting PostgreSQL using homebrew `brew services restart  postgresql`
3. Re-installing PostgreSQL using Homebrew
4. Updating PostgreSQL using Homebrew
5. I also tried following this [link](https://mccarthydanielle.medium.com/postgres-postmaster-pid-errors-5bdf3c2522fd) but when I run `cd Library/Application\ Support/Postgres` terminal tells me Postgres folder doesn't exist, so I'm kind of lost already. Although I have a feeling that deleting postmaster.pid would really fix my issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you're on mac, do take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71954046/8871869

Comment: Found the solution for MacBook apple silicon chips from the above comment. Just run the command after postgresql installation using homebrew  `createdb` followed by `psql`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Below was the workaround if you prefer to stay in v13.3, if you are on 14.2 you can simply change the port postgresql is listening to. Read their docs about it [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-postgres.html).

Note that this solution works for the setup that I have (take a look at the original post for my setup details ie. OS & how what I'd use to install Postgres)

1. open your postgresql.conf file in the following directory and use
   any text editor you want. below uses vscode/vim.

**vscode**

```
sudo code . /usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf
```

**vim**

```
sudo vi /usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf
```

2. change port to 5432 and restart your machine.

**v13.3 solution**

it appears that the upgrade really messed up my postgres since per Nagev's answer it's listening to port 5433 instead of 5432. I downgraded to v13.3 to fix this issue.

```
brew uninstall postgresql
brew install postgresql@13
brew services start postgresql@13
brew link postgresql@13 --force
```

Comment: uncommenting the `port = 5432` line worked for me

Comment: for v14, that is, package name postgresql@14, the `brew link` solution worked for me

Comment: To check if the port is not 5432 you can: `brew services info --all` -> find the PID for postgres in the output -> then `lsof -P -sTCP:LISTEN -i TCP -a -p <THE PID>`.  This will give you output which at the end should indicate the port, e.g. `localhost:5433 (LISTEN)`

Comment: Downgrading versions worked for me. Cheers!

Comment: for `postgresql@14` the `postgresql.conf` is in the same folder

Answer (score 73):

if you are using macOS and not M1

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
brew services restart postgresql
```

detail

- try `brew info postgresql` get execute command
- try `/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`
- error: `FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists`
- goto `/usr/local/var/postgres` directory, delete `postmaster.pid` file
- restart, works

Comment: Correct answer for me on macosx

Comment: this was the most helpful answer for me

Comment: You saved my day. I was almost uninstalling postgres.

Comment: I scoured the internet to find this.  You saved me from a whole lot of panic!

Comment: Had to manually remove postmaster.pid but it worked then upon restart!

Comment: `rm: /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid: No such file or directory` I got this. My directory has postmaster.opts though.

Comment: For my own benefit, I had to change "postgres" to "postgresql" and add my version.  So this worked for me: 
rm /usr/local/var/postgresql@14/postmaster.pid
brew services restart postgresql@14

Comment: PID file removal should have been added along with accepted answer. In the case of Postgres@14, the path to pid file is `/usr/local/var/postgresql@14/postmaster.pid`

Comment: Remove postmaster.pid file fixed my problem, thanks. I have the MacBook Pro 2020 Intel Core i5 and I'm using postgresql@15

Answer (score 63):

Solution for MacOS M1/M2/M3 on Monterey/Sonoma and later:

```
rm /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
brew services restart postgresql
```

Comment: brew services restart postgresql

The above command was all that I needed. Thanks!

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: This worked on 11.6 Big Sur (M1). I love you.

Comment: Worked for me for M1 MacOS Ventura

Comment: Worked for me M1 MacOS Ventura 13.3.1

Answer (score 28):

First up check whether Postgress is running

```
pgrep -l postgres
```

If it doesn't give you any result then let's try starting it using brew services.

```
brew services start postgresql
pgrep -l postgres
```

Still not running? Check the logs

```
tail /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log
```

You may see an error about a file named postmaster.pid:

```
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
```

This indicates that Postgres had not been shut down cleanly, for any number of reasons. Remove the stale PID lock then start the server again

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
brew services start postgresql
pgrep -l postgres
```

If you install the Postgress via home-brew then first create the postgres user.

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.7/bin/createuser -s postgres
```

Now you can log into it via following command:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Comment: This worked for me on M2 Sonoma 14.0

Answer (score 20):

If you use MacOS Homebrew, follow the instructions at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew
In short, try
`psql postgres`

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

For Mac with M1 use this:

```
brew services stop postgresql
rm /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14/postmaster.pid
brew services start postgresql
```

Comment: thanks @Artem, work for me in M1 chip ( macos vantire 13.0 )

Comment: Worked for me on M2 chip

Comment: First answer that worked for me on M2

Comment: Or `rm /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15/postmaster.pid` if your using postgres 15 (obviously).

Answer (score 7):

Worked on Mac OSX **M2** and installing `postgresql@15` using `brew`,

Installation steps that worked for me:

```
brew doctor
brew cleanup
brew update
brew install postgresql@15
```

Check installation path in the logs of this command  `brew install postgresql@15`, it might look like `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/bin`

Add to environment:

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

Append this line to the end of the file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/bin
```

Check this command, `brew services start postgresql@15` (Showed already started) and verify it's status, sometimes it will say its running but in the below command, it will show error.

```
brew services list
```

If status is running

```
 Name          Status  User  File
postgresql@15 started username ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@15.plist

brew link postgresql@15 --force
cd /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15
sudo vi postgresql.conf
```

Either uncomment or add in `postgresql.conf`

```
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
```

(From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71792068/7276869)

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
brew services restart postgresql
```

Try to start:

```
psql -d postgres -U username
postgres=# \l
```

(You have entered postgres shell!)

Answer (score 4):

In my case I received this issue after upgrading my Mac (pg 14.2 was the version).  I uninstalled it and reinstalled it a few times but it wouldn't start.  Even when it said it started, it didn't which was confusing.  I ended up needing to run the command below to get everything to work again.

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

Specifically I ran

```
brew install postgresql
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

It seems to me that the DB needed to be upgraded before it could run, once I did that it all came back.

Comment: What postgres version are you using?

Comment: Looks like it is 14.2 now, I thought is was 13 when I started this but it must have updated with all this.

Comment: I tried doing the same but I'm getting "Error: postgresql data already upgraded!", on 14.2 as well.

Comment: This is the right answer if you have some old databases before your new postgres installation.

Answer (score 3):

### Resetting PostgreSQL

My original answer only included the troubleshooting steps below, and a workaround. I now decided to properly fix it via brute force by removing all clusters and reinstalling, since I didn't have any data there to keep. It was something along these lines, on my Ubuntu 21.04 system:

```
sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 12 main
sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 14 main
sudo apt remove postgresql-14
sudo apt purge postgresql*
sudo apt install postgresql-14
```

Now I have:

```
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
14  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
```

And `sudo -u postgres psql` works fine. The service was started automatically but it can be done manually with `sudo systemctl start postgresql`.

Incidentally, I can recommend the [PostgreSQL docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/), which eliminates the need to bother with a local installation.

### Troubleshooting

Although I cannot provide an answer to your specific problem, I thought I'd share my troubleshooting steps, hoping that it might be of some help. It seems that you are on Mac, whereas I am running Ubuntu 21.04, so expect things to be different.

This is a client connection problem, as noted by [section 19.3.2 in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-start.html).

The directory in my error message is different:

```
$ sudo su postgres -c "psql"
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I checked what unix sockets I had in that directory:

```
$ ls -lah /var/run/postgresql/
total 8.0K
drwxrwsr-x  4 postgres postgres  160 Oct 29 16:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 36 root     root     1.1K Oct 29 14:08 ..
drwxr-s---  2 postgres postgres   40 Oct 29 14:33 12-main.pg_stat_tmp
drwxr-s---  2 postgres postgres  120 Oct 29 16:59 14-main.pg_stat_tmp
-rw-r--r--  1 postgres postgres    6 Oct 29 16:36 14-main.pid
srwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres    0 Oct 29 16:36 .s.PGSQL.5433
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres   70 Oct 29 16:36 .s.PGSQL.5433.lock
```

Makes sense, there is a socket for 5433 *not* 5432. I confirmed this by running:

```
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status                Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 down,binaries_missing postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
14  main    5433 online                postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
```

This explains how it got into this mess on my system. The default port is 5432, but after I upgraded from version 12 to 14, the server was setup to listen to 5433, presumably because it considered 5432 as already taken. Two alternatives here, get the server to listen on 5432 which is the client's default, or get the client to use 5433.

Let's try it by [changing the client's parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617370/postgresql-pgsql-client-expecting-sockets-in-different-location-from-postgrsql):

```
$ sudo su postgres -c "psql --port=5433"
psql (14.0 (Ubuntu 14.0-1.pgdg21.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

It worked! Now, to make it permanent I'm supposed to put this setting on a `psqlrc` or `~/.psqlrc` file. The [thin documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-psql.html) on this (under "Files") was not helpful to me as I was not sure on the syntax and my attempts did not change the client's default, so I moved on.

To change the server I looked for the `postgresql.conf` mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-CONFIGURATION-FILE) but could not find the file. I did however see `/var/lib/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.auto.conf` so I created it on the same directory with the content:

```
port = 5432
```

Restarted the server:  `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

But the error persisted because, as the logs confirmed, the port did not change:

```
$ tail /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
...
2021-10-29 16:36:12.195 UTC [25236] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5433
2021-10-29 16:36:12.198 UTC [25236] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433"
2021-10-29 16:36:12.204 UTC [25237] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-10-29 16:36:12 UTC
2021-10-29 16:36:12.210 UTC [25236] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

After other attempts did not succeed, I eventually decided to use a workaround: to redirect the client's requests on 5432 to 5433:

```
ln -s /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

This is what I have now:

```
$ ls -lah /var/run/postgresql/
total 8.0K
drwxrwsr-x  4 postgres postgres  160 Oct 29 16:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 36 root     root     1.1K Oct 29 14:08 ..
drwxr-s---  2 postgres postgres   40 Oct 29 14:33 12-main.pg_stat_tmp
drwxr-s---  2 postgres postgres  120 Oct 29 16:59 14-main.pg_stat_tmp
-rw-r--r--  1 postgres postgres    6 Oct 29 16:36 14-main.pid
lrwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres   33 Oct 29 16:40 .s.PGSQL.5432 -> /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433
srwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres    0 Oct 29 16:36 .s.PGSQL.5433
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres   70 Oct 29 16:36 .s.PGSQL.5433.lock
```

This means I can now just run `psql` without having to explicitly set the port to 5433. Now, this is a hack and I would not recommend it. But in my development system I am happy with it for now, because I don't have more time to spend on this. This is why I shared the steps and the links so that you can find a proper solution for your case.

Answer (score 3):

**For Mac**

```
brew uninstall --force postgresql@14
brew install postgresql@14
rm /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14/postmaster.pid
brew services start postgresql@14
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with a MacBook Pro with Intel

```
rm -f /usr/local/var/postgresql@14/postmaster.pid
```

Answer (score 2):

in this folder: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.7/bin`,
just run : `createdb postgresql`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I restored files onto a recovered and upgraded laptop. On Big Sur using postgres version 14, my postgres data directory had been

```
/usr/local/var/postgres
```

After brew installing postgres@14, it was looking and failing to find the data directory at

```
/usr/local/var/postgresql@14
```

The command `brew services restart postgres@14` confidently informed me that Postgres was running, but `psql -l` still returned the error in the post title.

What solved this for me was super simple:

```
cd /usr/local/var
ln -s postgres postgresql@14
```

Posting here in case this saves anyone the same trouble I had.

Answer (score 1):

The top answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633422/psql-fatal-database-user-does-not-exist) is what solved the issue for me. Basically run `createdb` in your terminal. This will create database for your logged in user. Then run `psql -h localhost` and you will be in!

Not saying this is the solve for all issues, but it solved mine.

Answer (score 1):

Check psql logs

```
1. /usr/local/var/log
2. check if server is UP and Running and if not (some error message or
 fatal will be there)
```

In my case there was a "FATAL: lock file 'postmaster.pid' already exists". This occurs when the PostgreSQL server (postmaster) is unable to start because the lock file, which is used to prevent multiple instances of the server from running simultaneously, already exists.

```
1. ps aux | grep postgres

2. sudo kill PID

3. brew services stop postgresql or sudo service postgresql stop
```

If you stopped the PostgreSQL server properly, the "postmaster.pid" file should have been removed automatically. However, if the server was terminated unexpectedly, the file might still exist. Navigate to the data directory of PostgreSQL (where the "postmaster.pid" file is stored) and delete the file manually:

```
4. sudo rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid(mac) || sudo rm /var/lib/postgresql/<version>/main/postmaster.pid(linux)



5. brew services start postgresql
```

These steps may fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`lunchy`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/lunchy) with homebrew, resolving this may be as simple as running three commands:

```
# Instead of uninstalling it, simply stop Postgres
lunchy stop postgres

# Remove the PID file that was left behind from improper shutdown
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid

# Restart Postgres
lunchy start postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is you have multiple clusters running so first check what the clusters are running by command:

```
pg_lsclusters
```

Then stop the unused cluster by command:

```
sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 11 main
sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 12 main
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your `pg` gem compiled to an old or different version of postgresql. Reinstalling the `pg` gem fixed it for me...

`gem uninstall pg`

`bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

This normally indicates that the server is not running on the default socket.

You should check that postgresql server is active. On Ubuntu you can run

```
service postgresql status
```

**psql** is command-line client used to interact with the database engine. If you do not have any use you should invoke it as a **postgres** user which is the database administrator. This can be achieved with sudo:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I previously `brew unlink postgresql@14` && `brew link libpq --force`
to get around [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643452/libssl-and-libcrypto-causing-dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-lib-libpq-5-dylib).

So I have to reverse it by `brew unlink libpq` && `brew link postgresql@14` .

I figure this out, bc I got same error in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632036/error-installing-postgresql-via-homebrew-on-mac) when I execute `initdb`  (use `locate` to find the one used by current postgres installation)

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.6/bin/initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8 /usr/local/var/postgres
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "XXX".
This user must also own the server process.

initdb: error: file "/usr/local/share/postgresql@14/postgres.bki" does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on an M1 Macbook Pro Ventura 13.0
I probably got this error when I accidentally closed my vscode or pgAdmin application while the server ran.
My error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:
```

Here is how I fixed it:

1. Check if postgres is running in the background using the `pgrep` command: `pgrep -l postgres`
2. Kill the running processes in the background using: `sudo pkill -u postgres`
3. Make sure that all the postgres processes are killed by repeating steps 1-2 until no processes are shown.
4. Run the `psql` command again.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is seeing this issue in "Nix" or "devenv shell" then you need to start the postgres service by using "start-postgres" command.

Answer (score 0):

Worth also checking that your main drive isn't full... In our case (on a debian based system):

```
df -H
```

Which showed that the root drive was 100% full.  Clearing some files and rebooting then resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As for Anyone who was this problem I wrote a medium article that explains in detail. https://medium.com/@createdbyken/activerecord-connectionnotestablished-postgresql-rails-m1-error-c63fe3bbde2b

But basically if you are runnning on MacOS (ventura) and you upgrade dependencies, the running path of postgresql has changed.
So instead of `brew services start postgres` you will use:
`pg_ctl -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgres start`

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked

```
brew uninstall postgres
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
rm /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log
rm -f ~/.psqlrc ~/.psql_history
```

then i checked if it really get installed by running this command

```
brew list --formula | grep -e postgres -e psql
```

after doing this i reinstalled by running `brew install postgresql@15`

and then i run this command

```
createdb `whoami`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
brew doctor
```

And do what it says if it gives you any instructions. Then running it again should give the output "Your system is ready to brew.". This is what worked for me, it was a brew problem not a postgresql problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

im using postgresql@15 installed from brew

I shut my laptop and terminated the psql tab on terminal badly and I was getting a
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

3 simple commands solved this issue

1. I did a `brew services stop postgresql@15`
2. a `rm postmaster.pid`, which I found in /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15
3. then finally a `brew services start postgresql@15`

now the `psql -d <database>` worked properly

Answer (score 0):

Try running postgresql manually: Attempt to start PostgreSQL manually from the command line to see if it provides more informative error messages:

```
pg_ctl -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/ start
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried most of the options above I couldn't really get them to work.

what worked for me is this. First I needed to know where is the current psql at, so I run.

```
which psql
```

then once I got the path I just I just looked for the exact location of postmaster.pid

then I deleted it , it looked like this in my case.

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgresql@15/postmaster.pid
```

finally the same path without postmaster.pid instead start

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgresql@15 start
```

that's it. good luck )

Answer (score -1):

1. brew uninstall postgresql
2. brew install postgresql
3. brew services stop postgresql
4. brew services start postgresql
5. restart your system

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answer, especially if you omit any explanation about why your answer helps to resolve the problem