# psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL: database "myname" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I a rails app running on my local environment using postgresql. This morning I spun up a new one and after install the pg gem, etc. I am running into the following error when trying to run

```
psql
```

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "jackcollins" does not exist
```

What's strange is the db name "jackcollins" is from my other rails app.

I ran

```
pgrep -l postgres
```

and the output was

```
20902 postgres
20919 postgres
20920 postgres
20921 postgres
20922 postgres
20923 postgres
20924 postgres
```

I'm unsure how to proceed so that these apps can both run their own postgres instance.

Comment: You will get more information if you do `ps ax | grep post`. It will show you if there is more then one instance of Postgres running.

Comment: It seems like you succeeded at doing what you want.  They do each have their own postgres instance, and one of those instances does not have a database by that name.

Comment: If you have more then one instance running then they will be listening on different ports. To get that then `sudo ss -tunlp | grep post` will show you what  ports they are listening on.

Answer (score 39):

I had the same problem as you, after making attempts to reinstall, rm -rf xxx.pid, etc., I ended up executing the following command and was eventually able to connect to the PostgreSQL database.

1. `brew install postgresql`
2. an error message appears
3. run `createdb` (because macs don't create username databases after installing PostgreSQL)
4. execute `psql` to connect successfully.

Comment: this worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the error,  you are trying to connect to `jackcollins`, please can you test trying to connect using the database flag?:

```
psql -d your_database_name
```

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of `-d <database_name>` `psql` will use the OS user name as the database name. As in many things it better to be explicit rather then implicit, especially when working on a new instance. In addition use `-h <host_name>`, `-p <port_number>` and `-U <user_name>`. Then you know who you are connecting as, as well as how. It is spelled out here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and since `psql` is a `libpq` program in more detail here [Key words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS).

Answer (score 1):

If you type

```
psql --help
```

in the terminal, you will see that the default database is your username. Unless you have that database in PostgreSQL, you will get an error. Instead, you can run the command

```
psql -d your_database_name
```

Also, if you want to log in as a specific user (by default it is a current user):

```
psql -d your_database_name -U your_username -W
```

The last -W is for password. Hope, it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm on an M2 mac and wasted waaay too long on this.

Simple solution, `brew uninstall postgresql` and [follow these simple instructions](https://postgresapp.com/) to install it by downloading the postgres.app and putting it in `/Applications`. The brew version is basically borked for me, but doing it manually go postgres working in less than 1 minute.

If you get

> “Postgres.app” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

> macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware.

Open system settings, type 'privacy and security' scroll down and allow 'Postgress.app':

[image]

#### One more thing

If you get some error like this (see that rails is still trying to interact with the uninstalled [brew] postgres):

```
rails db:create   
rails aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 0x0009): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: <E59F45B5-FCF8-3FF1-A0FA-68AB26D104B7> /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file) - /Users/st/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/lib/pg_ext.bundle
/Users/st/rails/myapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
/Users/st/rails/myapp/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/Users/st/rails/myapp/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

then just reinstall `pg` gem by going into your app

```
gem uninstall pg     

# Select gem to uninstall:
#  1. pg-1.5.3
#  2. pg-1.5.4
#  3. All versions

3
# Successfully uninstalled pg-1.5.3
# Successfully uninstalled pg-1.5.4

bundle
```