# psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed:

Tags: postgresql, sockets, apple-m1, postgresql-14

NOTE: I have a MacOS Monterey M1 chip.

After I put in the command line - psql postgres - I get the response state below.

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I have done the following already:

1. Restarting PostgreSQL using homebrew brew services restart  postgresql
2. Re-installing PostgreSQL using Homebrew

```
brew uninstall postgresql
```

3. Updating PostgreSQL using Homebrew

```
brew install postgresql@14
brew services start postgresql@14
brew link postgresql@14 --force
```

Comment: You should check service status and log files.

Comment: A) The server is not running. B) The server is running but not listening on port 5432. To your question add the complete `psql` command you are running.

Comment: Or C) the locations given in `unix_socket_directories` do not include '/tmp'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69754628/psql-error-connection-to-server-on-socket-tmp-s-pgsql-5432-failed-no-such)