# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL: role "{my_laptop_name1}" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working with a friend on a small Rails app to continue learning Rails, and I cloned his GitHub repository on my old laptop.

When I migrated everything to my new laptop the next day, I was forced to add a 1 at the end of my laptop user account, and for some reason this is showing up when I try to work on the app in the new laptop (specifically after running **rails db:migrate**):

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "my_laptop_name1" does not exist

I understand the new laptop is at the heart of the issue, I just can't figure out how/why.

I have tried many StackOverflow solutions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69754628/psql-error-connection-to-server-on-socket-tmp-s-pgsql-5432-failed-no-such)) but am not having much luck anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the process of installing Postgres on your old laptop, a Postgres role  was created that matches your shell login username. (Postgres uses the word "role" to mean what we think of as "user" - the person logging in)

In your new laptop Postgres doesn't have this role.

Things to check:

- if you installed Postgres on your new machine before you changed the username, maybe the old username exists as a role inside Postgres
- You can specify a user to `psql` using `psql -U my_laptop_name` (if you leave the -U off, postgres assumes that the role name is the same as your shell login name)
- if that works, you can change your db/config.yml to use the old role name
- if you want your database role/user name to be something else you can use the `postgres` cli, something like: `sudo -u postgres createuser <username>`

Comment: Thank you! I added my old laptop name in the config.yml file as you suggested, and this seems to have worked:

Comment: That's great to hear! Would you mind marking this answer as correct in that case?